# ASP.net webforms data annotations - is using dynamic data needed?

Tags: asp.net, data-annotations, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm hoping to generate my server-side and client-side validation (ish) using meta data on our entity classes.

I've been reading up on creating validators to use the meta data from data annotations.

However recently I've also been reading up about dynamic data.

Is my understanding corret in that the prescribed route to use data annoatations within web forms is to use asp.net dynamic data? As the custom validator tutorials seem a little old.

However, we are not using data binding as we are using the repository pattern with entity framework - does this mean we cannot use dynamic data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation annotation derives from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.  You can use the Dynamic Data one for ASP.NET web forms, or, [write your own](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-webforms-validation-with-data.html).